# Transpose data in Excel based on number of rows using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following sample data in Excel :-

```
Type    Reference  
AAA     R  
BBB     A  
ZZZ     R  
AAA     S  
BBB     A  
BBB     A  
ZZZ     S  
AAA     T  
BBB     A  
BBB     A  
ZZZ     T  
AAA     U  
BBB     A  
ZZZ     U
```

Type AAA is a header, and ZZZ is a footer.

I'd like to know if, using VBA, it is possible to output this sample data as such :-

```
AAA R   BBB A   ZZZ R  
AAA S   BBB A   ZZZ S  
AAA S   BBB A   ZZZ S  
AAA T   BBB A   ZZZ T  
AAA T   BBB A   ZZZ T  
AAA U   BBB A   ZZZ U
```

The logic being that the number of transposed rows for each header to footer group should equal the number of BBB rows between the header and footer

Comment: Do you have any code for us to assist with?

Comment: Yes. It's possible. It takes a little figuring how to do it though. Did you know that 80% of programming is in preparation? At this site we will help you with the encoding, the last 20% - and that only after you tried yourself.

Comment: @Variatus it is a bit more complicatet then it looks like if you have a look at the duplicated `AAA-S` and `AAA-T` values. So it took a bit more then a *"little figuring"* to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I poste an answer, because this is obviously not as trivial as it looks like.*

The tricky part here is that the headers `AAA` and footers `ZZZ` are occuring only once while the data `BBB` can have multiple lines. So if the data `BBB` is more than 1 line we also need to expand the headers and footers to the amount of data lines to get the OP's desired output.

My solution will not care about how the header, footer and data values are. It just assumes the following structure:

- `1` line header e.g. `AAA`
- `n` lines data e.g. `BBB`
- `1` line footer e.g. `ZZZ`

If the raw data follows this structure the code works.

This solution will read data from your sheet `Data`

[image]

and write it to the sheet `Output`

[image]

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ReorganizeData()
    Dim wsData As Worksheet 'data sheet
    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

    Dim wsOutput As Worksheet 'output sheet
    Set wsOutput = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    Dim Lastrow As Long 'find the end of the data
    Lastrow = wsData.Cells(wsData.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim iRowOutput As Long
    iRowOutput = 1 'this is where the output starts

    Dim HeaderRow As Long
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim FooterRow As Long

    Dim iRow As Long
    For iRow = 2 To Lastrow 'loop throug data
        If HeaderRow = 0 Then
            HeaderRow = iRow 'remember header row
        ElseIf StartRow = 0 Then
            StartRow = iRow 'remember where data BBB starts
        ElseIf Not wsData.Cells(iRow, "A").Value = wsData.Cells(iRow - 1, "A").Value Then
            EndRow = iRow - 1 'remeber where BBB ended
            FooterRow = iRow 'remember footer row

            'copy data to output sheet
            wsOutput.Cells(iRowOutput, "A").Resize(RowSize:=EndRow - StartRow + 1, ColumnSize:=2).Value = wsData.Cells(HeaderRow, "A").Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Value
            wsOutput.Cells(iRowOutput, "C").Resize(RowSize:=EndRow - StartRow + 1, ColumnSize:=2).Value = wsData.Cells(StartRow, "A").Resize(RowSize:=EndRow - StartRow + 1, ColumnSize:=2).Value
            wsOutput.Cells(iRowOutput, "E").Resize(RowSize:=EndRow - StartRow + 1, ColumnSize:=2).Value = wsData.Cells(FooterRow, "A").Resize(ColumnSize:=2).Value

            'calculate new output row
            iRowOutput = iRowOutput + EndRow - StartRow + 1

            'reset row finder variables
            HeaderRow = 0
            StartRow = 0
            EndRow = 0
            FooterRow = 0
        End If
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: Nice one PEH.  Yeah, at a quick glance, it looks pretty simple, but when you stop and see what's really going on, this is actually a bit challenging.